# Running testNG programmatically by pointing to an external jar throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, testng, classloader

I want to run TestNG tests programmatically by pointing to a jar which contains the test classes. For this, firstly the testng.xml is parsed and the classes are taken. Then each class is loaded into the classpath using the `URLCLassLoader`. But this throws `org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath:` exception.

Below is the code I tried

```
public void execute() {
    String testNGXmlPath = "/path/to/testng.xml";
    try {
        getClassesToLoad(testNGXmlPath);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add(testNGXmlPath);
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
}

public void getClassesToLoad(String path) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    File inputFile = new File(path);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("class");
    Element element;
    Node node;
    NamedNodeMap namedNodeMap;

    int i, length;
    length = nodeList.getLength();
    for (int j=0; j < length; j++) {
        element = (Element)nodeList.item(j);
        namedNodeMap = element.getAttributes();
        if (namedNodeMap != null) {
            for (i=0; i<namedNodeMap.getLength(); i++) {
                node = namedNodeMap.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeName() == "name") {
                    try {
                        loadClass("/path/to/testng.sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", node.getNodeValue());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void loadClass(String jarFilePath, String className) throws MalformedURLException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    File jarFile  = new File(jarFilePath);
    if (jarFile.isFile()) {
        URL url = jarFile.toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        cl.loadClass(className);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the class loader using the URLClassLoader, but for the classes that were loaded by your class loader to be visible to the current ContextualClassLoader, you need to set it up.

Please try doing it via `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader();` within your `loadClass()` method and then try running your test. This would ensure that when TestNG kicks in, it uses the `ContextClassLoader` that you injected to the current thread, to be used to load classes and thus help you get past your `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: Will not this remove the existing classes from the ContextClassLoader??

Comment: No it wouldnt if you instantiate your classloader as follows `URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url}, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());` because you are setting up the system class loader as the parent of your URL class loader.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to run your tests from a jar, you can simply package them and run using your xml.
Refer to the commandline section of the testng [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng).

Can refer to these [steps](https://niharikawhatsnext.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/running-maven-testng-tests-as-a-jar/) if yours is a maven project :